# Wrapper class for type_info

Tags: c++, typeid, typeinfo

So, I found this pretty nice tutorial about events in c++:

http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/effective-event-handling-in-c-r2459

BUT: the creator uses a wrapper for type_info returned by typeid. As far as I understand this is impossible due to the inaccessibility of the = operator of type_info. Thus, I can't compile the code he provides. Unfortunately, this is also the core part of the way his tutorial works. Now, how would I get around this problem, should I simply use the type_info.hash_code - does this work to individually identify a class ? Or didn't I understand what he means by "wrapper" in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only mention of `type_info` on that page is

> TypeInfo is a simple wrapper around type_info class that lets us store it as a key in std::map.

C++11 has `std::type_index` in `<typeindex>` which fulfills exactly this role. In general elements of a `map` do not need to be assignable, nor as of C++11 copyable, but `type_info` still cannot be used directly because you simply cannot construct one except by `typeid` expression.

The specification for `std::type_index` notes that it may contain a pointer to `std::type_info` to simplify implementation. "Wrapper" does not imply inheritance or direct membership.

An class which wraps by reference is also known as a *proxy.*

Comment: So, I don't even need any wrapper, I can simply use type_index directly ?

Comment: @user1071988 Yep, but it's part of C++11. You can probably get a canned version somewhere else. If that article doesn't actually provide source or a reference, that's sort of obnoxious, but check the usual suspects such as Boost. It's easy to write, despite the pointer, because every `type_info` object has indefinite lifetime. You can just initialize any pointer with `& typeid( foo )` because that's already a pointer to global.

Answer (score 0):

I asked myself the same question about this exact article, but then I realized that the code listing should have been provided, and it was. 
So `TypeInfo` is a straightforward wrapper around `type_info`.

```
class TypeInfo{
public:
    explicit TypeInfo(const type_info& info) : _typeInfo(info) {};
    bool operator < (const TypeInfo& rhs) const{
        return _typeInfo.before(rhs._typeInfo) != 0;
    }
private:
    const type_info& _typeInfo;
};
```